# Create equally divided ID per group with min and max using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe (sample):

```
import pandas as pd

min_id = 1
max_id = 10

data = [['A', 2], ['A', 3], ['A', 1], ['A', 4], ['A', 4], ['A', 2],
        ['B', 4], ['B', 5], ['B', 7], ['B', 4], ['B', 2],
        ['C', 1], ['C', 3], ['C', 2], ['C', 1], ['C', 5], ['C', 2] ,['C', 1],
        ['D', 1], ['D', 1], ['D', 1], ['D', 1]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data = data, columns = ['group', 'val'])

   group  val
0      A    2
1      A    3
2      A    1
3      A    4
4      A    4
5      A    2
6      B    4
7      B    5
8      B    7
9      B    4
10     B    2
11     C    1
12     C    3
13     C    2
14     C    1
15     C    5
16     C    2
17     C    1
18     D    1
19     D    1
20     D    1
21     D    1
```

I would like to create a column called "id" which shows the id with a min value of 1 (min_id) and a max value of 10 (max_id) per group. So the values between min and max depend on the number of rows per group. Here you can see the desired output:

```
data = [['A', 2, 1], ['A', 3, 2.8], ['A', 1, 4.6], ['A', 4, 6.4], ['A', 4, 8.2], ['A', 2, 10],
        ['B', 4, 1], ['B', 5, 3.25], ['B', 7, 5.5], ['B', 4, 7.75], ['B', 2, 10],
        ['C', 1, 1], ['C', 3, 2.5], ['C', 2, 4], ['C', 1, 5.5], ['C', 5, 7], ['C', 2, 8.5] ,['C', 1, 10],
        ['D', 1, 1], ['D', 1, 4], ['D', 1, 7], ['D', 1, 10]]
df_desired = pd.DataFrame(data = data, columns = ['group', 'val', 'id'])

   group  val     id
0      A    2   1.00
1      A    3   2.80
2      A    1   4.60
3      A    4   6.40
4      A    4   8.20
5      A    2  10.00
6      B    4   1.00
7      B    5   3.25
8      B    7   5.50
9      B    4   7.75
10     B    2  10.00
11     C    1   1.00
12     C    3   2.50
13     C    2   4.00
14     C    1   5.50
15     C    5   7.00
16     C    2   8.50
17     C    1  10.00
18     D    1   1.00
19     D    1   4.00
20     D    1   7.00
21     D    1  10.00
```

So I was wondering if anyone knows how to automatically create the column "id" using `pandas`? Please note that the number of rows could be way more then in the sample dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with [`numpy.linspace`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html):

```
df['ID']=df.groupby('group')['group'].transform(lambda x: np.linspace(min_id,max_id,len(x)))
print (df)

   group  val     ID
0      A    2   1.00
1      A    3   2.80
2      A    1   4.60
3      A    4   6.40
4      A    4   8.20
5      A    2  10.00
6      B    4   1.00
7      B    5   3.25
8      B    7   5.50
9      B    4   7.75
10     B    2  10.00
11     C    1   1.00
12     C    3   2.50
13     C    2   4.00
14     C    1   5.50
15     C    5   7.00
16     C    2   8.50
17     C    1  10.00
18     D    1   1.00
19     D    1   4.00
20     D    1   7.00
21     D    1  10.00
```

Comment: Ah, I could use `len(x)` of course, instead of first messing around with `.size` and having to explode again.